# How to pass array and string data in AJAX call to webmethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, devexpress

I want to update my data base with multiple parameter in that want to pass multiple parameters one of the parameters contain array List (Multiple selection of drop down which is storing in array List) and some are plane text. How I can pass all parameters in `JSON.stringfy(params)`

I am using *Devexpress* control (*ASPx DropDownEdit*) for multiple selection of plant Items.

**Parameters**

```
 
 PlantCode = checkListBox.GetSelectedItems();
 var PlantCode = {};
            PlantCode = checkListBox.GetSelectedItems();
            var ArrArr = $.map(PlantCode, function (n, i) {
                return [[n.text, n.value]];
            });
 var params = {
   'UserID': $('#txtUserIDEdit').val(),
   'UserName': $('#txtUserNameEdit').val(),
   'Password': $('#txtPassword').val(),
   'Status': $("input[name='Status']:checked").val(),
   'CreatedBy': $('#txtUserNameEdit').val(),
   'LocationCode': PlantCode
 };
```

**AJAX METHOD**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify(params),
  url: 'MobileUser_Login.aspx/UpdateRecord',
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (!data.error) {
      alert('Update Successfully !!');
    } else {
      alert(data.error);
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any other alternate to achieve same

While passing data I can see its throwing error

**Converting circular structure to JSON**

As per Naveen Suggestion I am trying to map through loop but i am not getting proper result.

```
var PlantCode = {};
            PlantCode = checkListBox.GetSelectedItems();

            var ArrArr = $.map(PlantCode, function (n, i) {
                return [[n.text, n.value]];
            });
```

After mapping i am getting array like this.

[image]

**Able to store Array List**

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, each object in the `GetSelectedItems` is referring to the same through `listEditBase` property. You will need to loop, map through the object and return a new array omitting the self reference

Comment: @naveen Thanks for your response Can you help me how can achieve same as you suggested